# Unable to establish socket communication between react and express js

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, socket.io, react-redux

I am declaring the socket in app.js(backend) in the following way

```
var createError = require('http-errors');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');
const cors = require('cors');
var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');
var usersRouter = require('./usersdata/users.controller');

var app = express();
//To start the app set DEBUG=api:* & npm start
// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'pug');
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(cors());


// Socket IO Require and object creation
const server = require('http').createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server, {pingTimeout: 60000});
const profileDataSocket=require('./sockets/profileDataSocket')
profileDataSocket(io);
```

profileDataSocket is declared as follows:-

```
const profileDataSocket = (io) => {
    io.on('connection', (socket) => {
      const con = new conService(io, socket);
      console.log('creating connection')
      socket.on(ON_PUSH_LOCATION, con.push_Location);
  
      socket.on('disconnect', ()=> {
      });
    });
  };
  
  module.exports = profileDataSocket;
```

and in the react i am using socket in this way:-

```
onSubmit() {
    console.log(this.state.formState.occupation);
    this.socket.emit('push message',{
      message:'Hello socket'
    })
    console.log('socket emmited');
  }
```

in react i am declaring socket client using:-

```
 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
    this.socket = io('http://localhost:9000')
  }
```

But I am getting the error in this way:-
**Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9000/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=NGVteci' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute**

**Note:-**My node is running at 9000 port and react is running on 3000 port

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is that CORS Policy. The Origin must match the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header. Here for more info: [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing)

Also in the express.js repositoy you can find some examples: [Configuring Cors - Express.js](https://github.com/expressjs/cors#configuring-cors)

To solve the issue I would do:

```js
const origin = 'http://localhost:9000'
app.use(cors({origin}))
```

Note: I would use the `origin` variable as an environment variable as: `process.env['allowed_origin']`

Comment: No still i am getting the same issue